# LSM and in-tree module compilation

Tags: module, kernel

I've been experimenting with the LSM functionality in the kernel. Writing, compiling and registering an LSM with the kernel is no issue.
The sources are located in security/mylsm. In addition, I would like to incorporate a kernel module (either loadable or built-in) that is built when a certain configuration parameter is defined (either y or m).
This module defines an interface to some of the data structures of the LSM (that are exported using EXPORT_SYMBOL) for monitoring the system and gathering data. Recompiling the kernel without the module needs to be done in order to remove the interface.

I have placed this module's source in the same directory as the LSM and am having some trouble writing the kbuild makefile. The module source is being compiled, the object files are being generated, however the module does not seem to be getting linked into the kernel image.

The makefile security/mylsm/Makefile looks as follows

```
obj-(CONFIG_MYLSM) += mylsm.o
mylsm.o := mylsm_src1.o mylsm_src2.o

obj-(CONFIG_MYLSM_DBGMOD) += mylsm_dbg_mod.o
```

Any idea as to where I might be missing something?

Comment: What value of `CONFIG_MYLSM` configuration option is?

Comment: It is a simple 'bool' kconfig flag that I have set to 'y'. I should note that CONFIG_MYLSM_DBGMOD' depends on CONFIG_MYLSM

Comment: Hmm, this: `however the module does not seem to be getting linked into the kernel image.` - why do you conclude that it is not linked into kernel?

Comment: I cannot locate the init and exit functions of my module in the System.map file after building and installing the kernel. Also, my printk's from the module unit aren't showing up in the kernel logs. Last but not least, the device file that the module should register is now shown under /dev/. The logic in the module should be fine.. it worked as an out of tree module.